# L2TP/IPSec stopped working after openssl upgrade

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

VPN connections from my MacBook / iOS devices to a Debian server having openswan / xl2tp were working just fine until I used apt-get to upgrade everything due to openssl heartbleed announcement.

Now the VPN connection stopped working with the following in the server auth.log:

```
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=109
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike] method set to=110
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [8f8d83826d246b6fc7a8a6a428c11de8]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [439b59f8ba676c4c7737ae22eab8f582]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [4d1e0e136deafa34c4f3ea9f02ec7285]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [80d0bb3def54565ee84645d4c85ce3ee]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [9909b64eed937c6573de52ace952fa6b]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03] meth=108, but already using method 110
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02] meth=107, but already using method 110
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02_n] meth=106, but already using method 110
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: ignoring Vendor ID payload [FRAGMENTATION 80000000]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: packet from x.x.x.x:500: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: responding to Main Mode from unknown peer x.x.x.x
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R0 to state STATE_MAIN_R1
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: STATE_MAIN_R1: sent MR1, expecting MI2
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: message ignored because it contains an unknown or unexpected payload type (ISAKMP_NEXT_SAK) at the outermost level
Apr 11 10:32:50 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: sending notification INVALID_PAYLOAD_TYPE to x.x.x.x:500
Apr 11 10:32:53 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: message ignored because it contains an unknown or unexpected payload type (ISAKMP_NEXT_SAK) at the outermost level
Apr 11 10:32:53 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: sending notification INVALID_PAYLOAD_TYPE to x.x.x.x:500
Apr 11 10:32:56 linode pluto[7868]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[1] x.x.x.x #1: message ignored because it contains an unknown or unexpected payload type (ISAKMP_NEXT_SAK) at the outermost level
```

and then the connection breaks.

Same type of connection used to generate this in the logs only 10 days ago:

```
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: responding to Main Mode from unknown peer y.y.y.y
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R0 to state STATE_MAIN_R1
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: STATE_MAIN_R1: sent MR1, expecting MI2
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike (MacOS X): peer is NATed
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R1 to state STATE_MAIN_R2
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: STATE_MAIN_R2: sent MR2, expecting MI3
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_INITIAL_CONTACT msgid=00000000
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: Main mode peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '192.168.2.101'
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[37] y.y.y.y #43: switched from "L2TP-PSK-NAT" to "L2TP-PSK-NAT"
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[38] y.y.y.y #43: deleting connection "L2TP-PSK-NAT" instance with peer y.y.y.y {isakmp=#0/ipsec=#0}
Apr  1 04:16:04 linode pluto[3093]: "L2TP-PSK-NAT"[38] y.y.y.y #43: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R2 to state STATE_MAIN_R3
```

etc.

My questions are:

1. What's the most apparent meaning of INVALID_PAYLOAD_TYPE error?
2. Other than downgrading openswan, what are my best options to investigate and fix this issue?

Comment: it looks like it can;t negotiate an IKE method (Internetwork Key Exchange), and despite trying multiple methods, still can't agree on one between the two peers.

Comment: I assume that IKE's must be configurable, somewhere?

Comment: nope, looks like an auto-negotiation fallback mechanism. probably defined by international standards. I'm thinking its because you have a mismatch between the software component capabilities on the peers. make sure both sides of the connection have been upgraded.

Comment: client side is mac os x / ios, so not much I can do really, what puzzles me is that it was working just fine, and googling only gives raspberry users that have similar issues and just downgrade to get it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encounterd the same problem today and I seems its caused by the latest security update of debian wheezy for openswan. When you do a `dpkg -l | grep openswan` I assume you have `1:2.6.37-3+deb7u1` installed.

To get it working with your iPad/ IPhone again you have to downgrade openswan on your server with `apt-get install openswan=1:2.6.37-3`.

Of course this is only an ugly workaround and I'm not sure if this is bug in the latest openswan or IOS, but let's hope either will fix it asap.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it does solve the problem, and I guess we will have to live with this for now.

Comment: I installed the patched deb from here and it works: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744717

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well. For anyone looking for openswan 1:2.6.37-3 for the raspberry pi, it is available here: http://snapshot.raspbian.org/201403301125/raspbian/pool/main/o/openswan/openswan_2.6.37-3_armhf.deb

Comment: Better yet, switch to strongswan if possible. Openswan is going to be removed from next debian release, afaik.